# Setting up sites in IIS7 on System that uses "Proxy" to get to Internet

Tags: iis, iis-7, proxy, web, localhost

I have configured two websites on IIS7 on system that does not uses proxy. Everything works fine.

I used the same procedures on a different system that uses a Proxy Server (DNS:172.16.0.1). There problem here is as soon as I setup Binding on the website(Like dev.mysite.com), everything breaks. Even the localhost does not show II7 home page. When I remove it the local host works fine but my sites do not work.

I tried to add exemptions for my local sites in Internet Explorer > Tools > Connection > Lan Setting > Advance but that did not solve the problem.

Can someone enlighten me where could be the problem. Basically the site work if I do not use Proxy Server (no extra software, simply DNS of our Server and dedicated IP Address) but with DNS setting (and configuring Gateway), my sites breaks. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had to add "Do not Use Proxy" for my local sites in FireFox. Go to Menu,

```
Tools  > Options > Advanced > Network Tab > Connection Setting.
```

Then enter you local domains separated by commas in the area "No Proxy for".